# List a count of similar filenames in a folder

Tags: unix, solaris

I have a folder which contains multiple files of a similar name (differentiated by a datetime in the filename)

I would like to be able to get a count of each file group/type in that folder.

i.e.

```
file1_25102019_111402.csv
file1_24102019_111502.csv
file1_23102019_121402.csv
file1_22102019_101402.csv

file2_25102019_161404.csv
file2_24102019_131205.csv
file2_23102019_121306.csv
```

I need to be able to return something like this;

```
file1 4
file2 3
```

**Ideally the answer would be something like "count of files whose first x characters are ABCD"**

The filenames can be anything. the date part in the example was just to demonstrate that the filenames begin with similar text but are distinghised by "something" further along in the name (in this case a date)

So I want to be able to Group them by the first X characters in the filename.

i.e. i want to be able to say, "give me counts of all files grouped by the first 4 characters, or the first 5 characters etc."

in SQL i'd do somthing like this

```
select   substr(object_name,1,5),
         count(*) 
from     all_objects 
group by substr(object_name,1,5)
```

Edited to show more examples;

```
File1weifwoeivnw
File15430293fjwnc
File15oiejfiwem
File2sidfsfe
File29fu09f4n
File29ewfoiwwf
File22sdiufsnvfvs
```

**Pseudo Code:**

**Example 1:**

```
ls count of first 4 characters
```

*Output*

```
File   7
```

**Example 2:**

```
ls count of first 5 characters
```

*Output*

```
File1    3
File2    4
```

**Example 3**

```
ls count of first 6 characters
```

*Output*

```
File1w    1
File15    2
File2s    1
File29    2
File22    1
```

Comment: Instead of writing *the answer would be something like "count of files whose first x characters are ABCD"*, please show the exact output you want to see for the file names shown in the question. Or if something else is wrong with my answer, specify the requirement for the solution that is not fulfilled. (I don't know how the output of your SQL command example would look like.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract the first 5 characters you can use

```
ls | cut -c1-5 | sort | uniq -c |awk '{ print $2,$1 }'
```

which prints for the first example from the question

```
file1 3
file2 3
```

If you want to have a different number of characters, change the `cut` command as necessary, e.g. `cut -c1-6` for the first 6 characters.

If you want to separate the fields with a TAB character instead of a space, change the `awk` command to

```
awk -vOFS=\\t '{ print $2,$1 }'
```

This would result in

```
file1   3
file2   3
```

---

Other solutions that work with the first example that shows file names with a date and time string, but don't work with the additional example added later:

With your first example files, the command

```
ls | sed 's/_[0-9]\{8\}_[0-9]\{6\}/_*/' | sort | uniq -c
```

prints

```
      3 file1_*.csv
      3 file2_*.csv
```

Explanation:

- The `sed` command replaces the sequence of a `_`, 8 digits, another `_` and another 6 digits with `_*`.
  With your first example file names, you will get `file1_*.csv` or
  `file2_*.csv` 3 times each.
- `sort` sorts the lines.
- `uniq -c` counts the number of subsequent lines that are equal.

Or if you want to strip everything from the first `_` up to the end, you can use

```
ls | sed 's/_.*//' | sort | uniq -c
```

which will print

```
      3 file1
      3 file2
```

You can add the `awk` command from the first solution to change the output format.

Comment: Thanks but the date format can be pretty much anything.

Ideally the answer would be somthing like "count of files whose first x characters are ABCD"

Comment: @joxo72 Then show examples for possible date formats in your question.

Comment: Ideally the answer would be somthing like "count of files whose first x characters are ABCD"

Comment: @joxo72 Please show the ideal output you would get for the example files in your question. The text "count of files whose first x characters are ABCD" doesn't show where you want to have the number.

Comment: I'll edit the question as comments won't let me put this neatly.

Comment: @joxo72Comments are for remarks about a question or answer, for suggestions or requests for clarification, not for adding information.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Bodo. I'm new to this :-)

Comment: thank you @Bodo, I've got it working now. I appreciate your help.